# How do I make an object move to certain point?

Tags: unity, c#, movement

I'm trying to force an object to move to a certain point, and stay there, without using `LookAt`.

This is what I've got, so far. I am trying to move my object to the position of `wak`.

```
public Transform airEye;
public Transform airship;

public float move_speed;
public Vector3 wak;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    wak = new Vector3( 
        airEye.transform.position.x,
        airEye.transform.position.y + 3,
        airEye.transform.position.z );
    // airship moves smoothly to wak point ?
}
```

How do I make an object move to a certain position?

Comment: It's no clear what you need... do you want it _to go to_ a certain location, or do you want it _to stay at_ a certain location?

Comment: Unclear !! airship moves to certain point (wak), and then stay there ?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77, note that the top two answers specifically mention that ***the asker*** has been the one to make changes to the code.

Comment: @Gnemlock you need to chill, man...

Comment: I think you guys may be *grossly* misinterpreting the intent of my edit. @AlexandreVaillancourt, I found it was easier to work off the prior edit to make the question make more sense, plain and simple. Feel free to read my answer on the meta, where I have listed all of the comparisons I made in making the edits.